# echo newline character output

Tags: bash, shell, echo, newline

I'm writing a bash script and when I write the line:

```
echo "l=l.split('\n')"
```

I would like the output to actually be `l=l.split('\n')` but get:

`l=l.split('
')`

Any idea on how to fix this? I tried using quotations at different spots and escaping the characters differently but nothing seems to be working. Appreciate the help!

**Worth noting - if I simply type the echo command into the terminal I get my desired output.. Not sure why a script is treated differently.

Comment: Escape the `\ ` in `\n`: `echo "l=l.split('\\n')"`?

Comment: Just tried that solution again and received the output:                    `l=l.split(                                                                 ')`.. Basically the same thing except the first apostrophe in the parentheses is missing

Comment: It works for me using bash 4.2.37; I get the `\n` in the output.

Comment: Which way works? @KeithThompson

Comment: @15tigers: Both `echo "l=l.split('\n')"` and `echo "l=l.split('\\n')"` print `l=l.split('\n')` for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves the problem.

```
echo "l=l.split('\\\n')"
```

Comment: For me, that prints `l=l.split('\\n')` (bash 4.2.37).

Comment: Using bash 4.2.45, that's not works, Moreover the @ExP comment just works ok.

Comment: Oh... I saw it now. `sh file.sh` gives the correct output, `bash file.sh` gives extra '\'.

Comment: Asker may be using `sh` to run the file.

Comment: Not sure why but this answer worked for me, and I'm using bash version 3.2.51. Not totally sure how to upgrade but will look into it. Thanks all!

Comment: Yeah @ShashwatKumar that's what I am doing

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like perhaps you got the shebang wrong (for a `bash` script, anyway). Take for example:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/sh

echo "l=l.split('\n')"
$ ./test.sh
l=l.split('
')
$ cat test.bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "l=l.split('\n')"
$ ./test.bash
l=l.split('\n')
```

Even though `bash` and `sh` may be provided by the same shell on some systems, there are subtle differences in their behavior. If you want it to behave like it does for you in a terminal, be sure to use `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: +1 - I do think that's the issue; my guess is that the OP uses OSX, where the difference you describe applies.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

- **If your script is really being run by `bash`**, then something must have turned on the off-by-default `xpg_echo` shell option - either directly, or indirectly via shell option `posix`.
  `posix` is *implicitly* turned on when Bash is invoked as `sh` (`/bin/sh`), which happens on macOS, for instance.
- **If your script is *not* being run by `bash`**, which is the likeliest explanation, as suggested in [FatalError's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22673909/45375):

  - Ensure that your script's shebang line is either
    `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`.
  - Alternatively, pass it directly to `bash`: `bash <script>`
- The **portable solution**, which shields you from variable `echo` behavior, is to use `printf` as follows:

  ```
  printf '%s\n' "l=l.split('\n')"
  ```

---

#### Optional background information

In `bash`, the interpretation of escape sequences such as `\n` by `echo` is turned OFF by default.

**Option `xpg_echo` must be turned on for escape sequences to be recognized by `echo`**.

This **option is *implicitly* on if you run `bash` in POSIX compatibility mode** (verify with `shopt -o posix`), which **also happens if you run Bash as `sh`**, as is the case on **macOS**, for instance, where `/bin/sh` is Bash.

Note that irrespective of the state of `xpg_echo` by itself, **you can opt into escape-sequence interpretation ad-hoc with `echo -e` and opt out with `echo -E`**.

However, **this does *not* work when running in POSIX compatibility mode (`shopt -o posix`)**, where - in compliance with POSIX - **`echo` supports no options at all**.

In other words: The following would only work if (a) your script is really being executed by `bash` and (b) option `posix` is *off*:

```
echo -E "l=l.split('\n')"
```

Again, **`printf` is the *portable*, [POSIX-compliant alternative](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html)** that **works consistently across all POSIX-compatible shells, irrespective of the state of shell options**:

```
# '%s\n': *without* escape-sequence interpretation
$ printf '%s\n' "l=l.split('\n')"
l=l.split('\n')

# '%b\n': *with* escape-sequence interpretation
$ printf '%b\n' "l=l.split('\n')"
l=l.split('
')
```